# Ios stackviews top bonus bar

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistackview

I want to get a "bonus bar" at the top of my scene, something similar to what one can see in many games such as candy crush. Here is the design I am trying to get in my storyboard :
[image]

I want it to fill equally (= one third of the screen width for each bonus), so I think I should use stackviews with a "fill equally" ditribution. But I don't know how to make the design for each bonus. I guess I need a label for the number, a label for the "+", an imageview for the yellow icon and another imageview for the pink background. How to put together these elements ? I tried to use stackviews within stackviews but I don't manage to get what I want.

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: @ Alexr9494 Take a imageview for star and a label to display score , you can give background color and corner radius to the same label, instead of using imageview.

Comment: The same thing which coder said additionally just add uiview as a parent of all other Star imageview,label & button(add).set bg color of view. Make sure label position should be under the star image view.Instead of stack view make parent view width eqauls to main view & set parent view width multiplier 0.32(100/3 = 0.3333  adjust based on space if you want).copy & do same for other two view.

Comment: Take a imageView for star with rounded corner. Take another UIView for pink background. Within this view take one label and button (for plus icon if required). Then You can combine these 3 Views within a StackView with equal distribution or you can use constraint as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works now. It is not easy to master constraints :D  I guess it is powerful when you master it. Thank you for the corner radius and the width multiplier tips, I am sure that I will use them often !